# Tomcat 8 Slow startup with deployWAR

Tags: performance, tomcat

I went from Tomcat 7.0.54 to 8.0.15, upgraded openSSL to 1.0.1k and tcnative to the latest 1.1.32 with APR 1.5.1.

However, Tomcat now starts about 2 to 3 times slower than before. Most noticeably, it takes alot longer to deploy WAR files.

Tomcat 7

```
Jan 20, 2015 3:39:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive <PATH>\file.war has finished in 433 ms
```

Tomcat 8

```
Jan 21, 2015 2:27:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive <PATH>\file.war has finished in 4,310 ms
```

This happens to all WAR files, all went from milliseconds to around 5 seconds.

I removed the JasperListener from the server.xml because it appears to have been removed.

```
unpackWARs="false"
autoDeploy="true"
```

unpackWars does not make a difference if set to true (atleast not noticable).
I thought it might have been the annotation scanning issue fixed in 8.0.17, but no luck.

I noticed that jarsToSkip in catalina.properties changed from

```
tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip to
tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip
```

and that 
org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.jarsToSkip was removed and went to context.xml

```
<JarScanner>
    <JarScanFilter tldSkip="websocket-api.jar,tomcat-websocket.jar"/>
</JarScanner>
```

However, none of this seems to bring me back to the performance of tomcat 7. The one action that did do it, was removing the websocket jars. However we need them. This brings me to the conclusion that they are still scanned, even though they should be skipped.

Am I missing something? Does the context.xml not do the same as the catalina.properties jarsToSkip?

Comment: The filenames of the jars you want to skip may have changed... probably worth checking you're actually skipping what you think you're skipping

Answer (score 17):

The solution for slow startup in general for me was to put
in conf/context.xml:

```
<Context>
    <JarScanner>
        <JarScanFilter defaultPluggabilityScan="false" />
    </JarScanner>
</Context>
```

Source:
https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/#!topic/sakai-dev/cjtYGxd6hG0

EDIT Oct-2022:

Adding a scanManifest="false" attribute to <JarScanner> tag may speed up the loading process even further:

```
<JarScanner scanManifest="false">
    <JarScanFilter defaultPluggabilityScan="false" />
</JarScanner>
```

Comment: This took my application startup time down from around 22k to 1.2k.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure unpackWARs="true" is not making a difference for you?

There's an ongoing discussion about this topic in bugzilla:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57251

There it has been established that Tomcat 8's behaviour when unpackWARs="false" will be noticeably slower because of an implementation simplification performed in the code.

Comment: I am. I now only have unpacked WARs but it does not make a visible difference. I think whatever is wrong takes up so much time the effect of the other fixes are not noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I am having similar problems here.

One option that improved the startup time was to add:

```
metadata-complete="true"
```

to the web.xml (webapp element), as recommended in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp. This assumes your web.xml is all what your web-app needs to boot.

It didn't totally fix the issue for me, but startup speed improvement was substantial.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me it does not make a lot of a difference. I see maybe a 2 second improvement in total. That's not much since it still about 40 seconds slower than before. Most was to gain with parallel start up, but I would like to get the deployment times back down to about 250ms.

Comment: The wiki link has moved here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp

Answer (score 1):

you can try parallelism for startup by changing
in `conf/server.xml`
host element attribute `<Host ... startStopThreads="0"/>`